# Android: How do I modify my Custom ListView adapter so that it puts successive TextViews on the same line if there is room?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter, custom-adapter

I am looking for a way to modify my custom listadapter so that the TextViews will start at the end of the previous text views in the list.

Each section of text can vary in length, and they are usually several lines. Let's say these are two of my portions of text.

Text 1:
**"Section 1: The tiger ran up to the log. He stopped for a moment to smell his surroundings."**

Text 2:
**"Section 2: He didn't smell anything. He continued on his journey."**

With my current set up, these display like this(I've added line breaks to simulate the Android screen size and to emphasize what I mean):

**Section 1: The tiger ran up to the log. He stopped for**

**a moment to smell his surroundings.**

**Section 2: He didn't smell anything. He continued on**

**his journey.**

How I would like it to display, is like this:

**Section 1: The tiger ran up to the log. He stopped for**

**a moment to smell his surroundings. Section 2: He**

**didn't smell anything. He continued on his journey.**

Does that make sense? The problem is that the amount of Sections can vary, and I need this to work for each successive set of text. For example, Section 3 should continue on the same line as Section 2, if there is additional room.

Here is my current setup, though there isn't a lot here, it's pretty basic.

My ListView:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_list_view"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
tools:context="com.name.appname.ActivityName"
>

<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"

    >
</ListView>



</LinearLayout>
```

My TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/list_view_layout"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/default_text"
    android:id="@+id/thetext"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My List Adapter:

```
  public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClassObject>
{
    public MyListAdapter()
    {

        super(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_display_button, List);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View itemView = convertView;

        if (itemView == null)
        {
            itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_display_button, parent, false);
        }

        TextView Text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thetext);

        Text.setText(List.get(position).getText());

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you concatenate the strings together and put them in a single TextView?  You can use a SpannableString for markup to make sections look distinct, if you need to.  You won't be able to get individual list items to display like a flow layout without some custom code, i.e. a LayoutManager for a RecyclerView.

Comment: Mostly for simplicity sake. I want to be able to select each section individually to perform actions for that particular section.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a standard adapter. Standard list adapters bind every element (String in your case) to a new view. The views are converted into individual list rows in the listview. So, unless you want to create a custom listview/adapter, each String will appear in it's own row. It'd probably be easiest to just do what the previous commenter suggests: concatenate your Strings and use one view.

Comment: I recommend you look at putting HTML with separate section links into a single TextView, or maybe even using WebView for the HTML and handling some user events in JavaScript. That will be simpler than trying to bash a ListView and adapter into something that will do what you want.

Comment: I guess I've been looking at things like taking two separate textviews and giving them the same layout weight which puts them on the same line. Could something similar not be done with the new text views being created for the listview? I might be grasping here.

And in response to hungryghost, would there be no way to have the position of the next generate row start on the previous row? or is that just not how listviews work?

Sounds like I might just have a poor understanding of listviews.

Comment: That's not how listviews work. Listviews bind one view/row per data element/object. You could probably write a custom listview that does things differently, but it sounds like you're just looking for another kind of layout or widget. If you want something that handles appending and wrapping of text, a textview already does that. If you need to maintain different blocks of text within that textview, maybe try what the other commenter suggested?

Comment: Appreciate the help. The textview was the right answer. Thank you both.